# For cordova PushPlugins, how to change from developement mode to distribution mode for iOS apps

Tags: ios, cordova, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I finished creating phonegap based iOS app that uses PushPlugins.
I went through all provisioning profile, p12, certificates, etc for pushplugins for iOS as **DEVELOPMENT mode ( not distribution mode).**

Now I am ready to distribute my app in app store, but I am having trouble converting from development mode -> distribution mode regarding PushPlugins.
I spent so many days on this googling, but i couldn't get things right.

I followed these steps to implement APN notification in iPhones.

1. http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1
2. https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

and here is what i did for distribution mode.

1. Open Keychain Access on Mac and choose the menu option Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority
2. Save the private key as MyAppNameHere.p12
3. Created new AppID as:

   - App ID Description: MyAppName
   - App Services Check the Push Notifications Checkbox
   - Explicit App ID: com.mycompanynamehere.myappnamehere
4. Add iOS Certificate to this newly created app id
5. made .pem files

   - penssl x509 -in aps_production.cer -inform der -out myappCERT.pem
   - openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out myappKEY.pem -in MyAppNameHere.p12
6. cat myappCERT.pem myappKEY.pem -> ck.pem
7. created new provisioning profile for App Store
8. Add this provisioning profile to Xcode.

I was able to get things work with aps_development.cer, but failed to do the same thing with aps_production.cer

Can anyone give me good tutorials on this?? 
Phonegape + PushPlugins for distribution purpose.

Comment: can you explain this part? "I was able to get things work with aps_development.cer, but failed to do the same thing with aps_production.cer"

Comment: I got aps_production.cer ( also aps_development.cer) by: https://developer.apple.com -> created new App ID -> after creating new App ID, click on Edit -> scroll down to Push Notifications section(Apple Push Notification service SSL Certificates) -> there are two types : Development SSL Certificate and Production SSL Certificate. I clicked on 'create certificate' of 'Production SSL Certificate' section. -> Upload CSR file.(Select .certSigningRequest file saved on your Mac.). Doing this, I downloaded aps_production.cer

Comment: Before doing this, I went with 'Development SSL Certificate' -> downloaded aps_development.cer and made my way through the rest of tutorials of the link mentioned above, and was able to send and receive APN Notifications. But wasn't successful with aps_production.cer

Comment: You have to install the app in production mode to make the production certificate work. You can do this uploading the app to itunes connect and install it as betatester, or upload it to your own server as ad-hoc distribution or install it with itunes

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. If I upload my app as ad-hoc, i can still test APN notification again before fully uploading it to app store, right?

Comment: yes, you can test the notifications with the production certificate, and you have to configure your server to send the push notification to the apple production server

Comment: Thanks I posted ur comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

According to comments from jcesarmobile,
"You have to install the app in production mode to make the production certificate work. You can do this uploading the app to itunes connect and install it as betatester, or upload it to your own server as ad-hoc distribution or install it with itunes"
This solved my case